# Unity3d Interactive pause menu that has uses Input.GetAxis to Navigate the new UI

Tags: c#, user-interface, unity-game-engine

Okay So I'm trying to create an interactive pause menu that has access to Input.GetAxis using Unity 4.6's new UI.

As long as the Navigation relationships are set up for the selectable elements (In my case a series of buttons) and `Interactable` is set to true then the UI works just fine but, when I set the `Time.timeScale = 0.0f;` then keyboard input navigation no longer works. However the mouse input clicks and animation still work as intended.

I've tried several different ways to get around the time scale problem and the best I've got so far is checking the value returned from `Input.GetAxis()` while in the body of the `Update` message of the `MonoBehavor` base object. This somewhat works but my results are either the very top or very bottom of the Button selected collection. I'm thinking this is because update gets called a great deal more than `FixedUpdate` and would make sense if my console printed out more call to the method that moves up and down the selection. So with that I'm thinking its one of those "office space" type errors, off by 1 decimal place or something silly but I just can't seem to see it. Otherwise I think my solution would be a fairly viable work around.

The following is an image of my Unity Setup with mentioned game objects in Unity 4.6 followed by my code.

[image]

```
public class PlayerInGameMenu : MonoBehaviour
{
  public EventSystem eventSystem;

  Selectable SelectedButton;
  public Selectable Status;
  public Selectable Settings;
  public Selectable Save;
  public Selectable Quit;

  public bool Paused;

  List<Selectable> buttons;
  int selecteButtonIndex = 0;

  public Canvas Menu;

  void Start()
  {
    Menu.enabled = false;
    buttons = new List<Selectable>();
    buttons.Add(Status);
    buttons.Add(Settings);
    buttons.Add(Save);
    buttons.Add(Quit);
    SelectedButton = buttons[0];

  }

  void Update()
  {

    CheckInput();

    if (Paused && !Menu.enabled)
    {
      ShowMenu();
    }
    else if (!Paused && Menu.enabled)
    {
      HideMenu();
    }
  }

  void ShowMenu()
  {
    Paused = true;
    Menu.enabled = true;
    Time.timeScale = 0.0f;
  }

  void HideMenu()
  {
    if (Menu.enabled)
    {
      Paused = false;
      Menu.enabled = false;
      Time.timeScale = 1.0f;
    }
  }

  void CheckInput()
  {
    if (cInput.GetKeyDown("Pause"))
    {
      Paused = !Paused;
      SelectedButton = buttons[selecteButtonIndex];
      eventSystem.SetSelectedGameObject(SelectedButton.gameObject, new BaseEventData(eventSystem));
    }

    if (Paused)
    {
      float v = cInput.GetAxis("Vertical");

      //to attempt to cut down on the input sensitity I am checking 0.5 instead of just 0.0
      if (v >= 0.5)
      {
          GoDown();
      }
      else if (v <= -0.5)
      {
          GoUp();
      }
    }
  }

  void GoDown()
  {
    //go to the last button available if we go past the index
    if (selecteButtonIndex > buttons.Count - 1)
    {
      selecteButtonIndex = buttons.Count - 1;
    }
    else
    {
      selecteButtonIndex = selecteButtonIndex + 1;
    }
  }

  //go to the first button available if we go past the index
  void GoUp()
  {
    if (selecteButtonIndex < 0)
    {
      selecteButtonIndex = 0;
    }
    else
    {
      selecteButtonIndex = selecteButtonIndex - 1;
    }
  }
}
```

I know its in beta but I'm wondering if you are going to implement navigation why would you design it in such a way that `Time.timeScale=0.0f;` (the easy way to pause a game) does not work with the UI button navigation naturally. Problems for minds greater than I maybe?  Or there is a simple way to do it and I just do not know what bit I need to flip.

I've also considered just freezing rigid bodies on pause but that seems like will require a huge time investment in my existing code base and will not be a universal solution across all game objects particularly colliders that do not rely on Rigid bodies and particle systems. I'm pretty open minded about solutions but it seems like there should be a really easy way to do this.

Comment: I have noted that using GetAxisRaw while timescale is 0 sometimes works better than GetAxis.

Comment: Tried it, didn't change the outcome.

Comment: It did help though, thanks Imapler.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay so my solution to this problem was to utilize `Time.realtimeSinceStartup` to check for input on fixed intervals and develop an abstract class that inherits from MonoBehavior. What that looks like in code:

```
public abstract class RealtimeMonoBehavior:MonoBehaviour
{
  public float updateInterval = 0.5F;
  private double lastInterval;

  void Start()
  {
    DefaultIntervalStart();
    lastInterval = Time.realtimeSinceStartup;
    RealtimeIntervalStart();
  }

  void Update()
  {
    DefaultIntervalUpdate();
    float timeNow = Time.realtimeSinceStartup;
    if (timeNow > lastInterval + updateInterval)
    {
      lastInterval = timeNow;
      RealtimeIntervalUpdate();
    }
  }

  public virtual void DefaultIntervalUpdate(){}
  public virtual void DefaultIntervalStart(){}
  public virtual void RealtimeIntervalStart(){}
  public virtual void RealtimeIntervalUpdate(){}

}
```

And here is what my code looks like after implementing the change

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using UnityEngine.Events;
using Extensions;
using UnityEngine.EventSystems;


public class PlayerInGameMenu : RealtimeMonoBehavior
{
  public EventSystem eventSystem;

  Selectable SelectedButton;

  public Selectable Status;
  public Selectable Settings;
  public Selectable Save;
  public Selectable Quit;

  public float ButtonThreashold;

  public bool Paused;

  List<Selectable> buttons;
  int selectedButtonIndex;

  public PlayerMovement PlayerMovement;

  public Canvas Menu;

  public override void RealtimeIntervalStart()
  {
    base.RealtimeIntervalStart();
    Menu.enabled = false;
    buttons = new List<Selectable>();
    buttons.Add(Status);
    buttons.Add(Settings);
    buttons.Add(Save);
    buttons.Add(Quit);
    selectedButtonIndex = 0;
    SelectedButton = buttons[selectedButtonIndex];
    eventSystem.SetSelectedGameObject(SelectedButton.gameObject, new BaseEventData(eventSystem));

  }

  public override void DefaultIntervalUpdate()
  {
    base.DefaultIntervalUpdate();
    if (cInput.GetKeyDown("Pause"))
    {
      Paused = !Paused;
    }
  }

  public override void RealtimeIntervalUpdate()
  {
    base.RealtimeIntervalUpdate();

    CheckInput();

    if (Paused && !Menu.enabled)
    {
      ShowMenu();
    }
    else if (!Paused && Menu.enabled)
    {
      HideMenu();
    }
  }

  void ShowMenu()
  {
    Paused = true;
    Menu.enabled = true;
    Time.timeScale = 0.0f;
  }

  void HideMenu()
  {
    if (Menu.enabled)
    {
      Paused = false;
      Menu.enabled = false;
      Time.timeScale = 1.0f;
    }
  }

  void CheckInput()
  {
    if (Paused)
    {
      float v = Input.GetAxisRaw("Vertical");

      if (v > ButtonThreashold)
      {
        GoUp();
      }
      else if (v < -ButtonThreashold)
      {
        GoDown();
      }
      SelectedButton = buttons[selectedButtonIndex];
      eventSystem.SetSelectedGameObject(SelectedButton.gameObject, new BaseEventData(eventSystem));
    }
  }

  void GoDown()
  {
    if (selectedButtonIndex < buttons.Count - 1)
    {
      selectedButtonIndex = selectedButtonIndex + 1;
    }
  }

  void GoUp()
  {
    if (selectedButtonIndex > 0)
    {
      selectedButtonIndex = selectedButtonIndex - 1;
    }
  }
}
```

Nod to [imapler](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2885785/imapler), [Input.GetAxisRaw](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Input.GetAxisRaw.html) feels better for checking the input.

Answer (score 1):

This worked like a charm:

```
    var v = Input.GetAxisRaw("JoyY1"); // Or "Vertical"

    if (Math.Abs(v) > ButtonThreashold)
    {
        var currentlySelected = EventSystem.currentSelectedGameObject
            ? EventSystem.currentSelectedGameObject.GetComponent<Selectable>()
            : FindObjectOfType<Selectable>();

        Selectable nextToSelect = null;

        if (v > ButtonThreashold)
        {
            nextToSelect = currentlySelected.FindSelectableOnUp();
        }
        else if (v < -ButtonThreashold)
        {
            nextToSelect = currentlySelected.FindSelectableOnDown();
        }

        if (nextToSelect)
        {
            EventSystem.SetSelectedGameObject(nextToSelect.gameObject);
        }
    }
```